# User control in c#.net

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

```
IDE: Microsoft Visual Studio 2010
Platform: C#.net
```

I have a form which is having user control on it. I want to know whenever I click on any part of the user control my whole application hangs up in C#.net. And also that control is having labels, and when I click on the labels it should load an MDI parent and the child form it points to.Any suggestions?

**Updated:**

```
 label2.Location = new Point(922, 10);
 label2.Visible = true;
 lblQuickSetup.Visible = true; 
 rectangleShape2.Visible = true;
 Background bg = new Background();
 Form f = this.Parent as Form;
 bg.MdiParent = f;
 bg.Show();
```

Comment: Could you please post relevant code?

Comment: remove this comment and edit your question with this code, as you can see code in comments section is not readable

Comment: Try to step-by-step debug (set breakpoint on the first line in listed code, run, once you click something, it should stop, then do `step` by pressing `F11` until it hangs up, note the line, tell us).

Comment: Couldn't get much clarity regarding what is happening in your code.. But in a general view, use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke with background priority.

Comment: Where should i use this?